# Slow hd in Ubuntu 12.04 Intel Sandybridge mobile

Tags: video, intel

I got a computer with a preinstalled version of Windows 7 but I decided to install Ubuntu, but there is a problem during the hard drive is too slow. I have an Intel Sandybridge mobile graphic controller, an Intel Core i5 processor 2,4 GHZ, 4 GB ram, what should I do?

Comment: Having the same problem!